# How to find pattern upper case sentence

Tags: python, regex

I have a texte file like following

```
FAKE ET FAKE
1, rue Fake - 99567 FAKE
Tél, :00 99 89 22 34 © fake@fake-fake.fr
FAKE-ET-FAKE.fr

FAKE AGAIN
2, rue Fake - 99567 FAKE
Tél, :00 99 89 22 34 © fake@fake-fake.fr
FAKE-AGAIN.fr 

STILL FAKE AGAIN ANOTHER
2, rue Fake - 99567 FAKE
Tél, :00 99 89 22 34 © fake@fake-fake.fr
STILL-FAKE-AGAIN-ANOTHER.fr
```

with a `regex` I want to extract the header of each paragraph.
I know that the pattern of the header is to be upper case separated with space but the number of upper case words and spaces is different

I have tried this but problem is I do not manage to make it work wathever the number of pattern "UPPER UPPER UPPER ..."

here what I have tried:

```
regex = r'[A-Z]+\s[A-Z]+'
re.findall(regex, text)
```

Here I would only find "FAKE AGAIN" in my example.

I have tried

```
regex = r'([A-Z]+\s[A-Z]+)+'
```

to say that this pattern of `UPPER\s` can reproduce but did not work

Comment: Is the header always preceded by a blank line?  If so, then `text.split('\n\n')` will separate the whole thing into individual blocks.  No regex required.

Comment: Good idea but This was just for the example, my blocks are not so regular

Comment: Idea: `regex = r'[A-Z]+(?:[^\S\n][A-Z]+)+'`

Comment: awesome @RyszardCzech, that perfectly did the job !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```py
regex = r'[A-Z]+(?:[^\S\n][A-Z]+)+'
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/3YFMIL/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```
 - [A-Z]+ - Match a single character in the range between A (index 65) and Z (index 90) (case sensitive) between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
 - Non-capturing group (?:[^\S\n][A-Z]+)+
   - + - matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   - Match a single character not present in the list below [^\S\n]
      - \S - matches any non-whitespace character (equivalent to [^\r\n\t\f\v ])
      - \n - matches a line-feed (newline) character (ASCII 10)
   - Match a single character present in the list below [A-Z]
      - + -  matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
      - A-Z - matches a single character in the range between A (index 65) and Z (index 90) (case sensitive)
```

Answer (score 0):

With `x.txt` containing your text, the following worked fine for me:

```
egrep -e '^[A-Z][A-Z ]*$' x.txt
```